# Send one view's data to another controller form in yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to send one view's data to another controller _form

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'fee-collection-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search1($id),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    //'id',
    //'stud_id',
    //'fee_list_id',
    array(          
        'name'=>'fee_list_id',
        'value'=>'$data->feeList->particular_id',
    ),
    'amount',
    'discount',
    'month',
    'start_date',
    'due_date',
    'payable_amount',
    array(
            'header' => 'Status',
             'value' => '"Paied"', 
        ),
        array(
                    'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
                     'urlExpression'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("feeTransaction/create",
                     array("fee_collection_id"=>$data->id,"amount"=>$data->amount,
                     "month"=>$data->month,"stud_id"=>$data->stud_id))',
                    'label'=> 'Pay Fee'
                    ),




),
)); ?>
```

And I want  `'class'=>'CLinkColumn',` url attributes
To be viewed in another controller _form (i.e id,stud_id,amount,month) fields.
For example, when i want to pay fee of student, i click on link which use above mentioned code and redirect to new page. In the text fields i need student name against student id, amount and month
Any suggestion how can i achieve it?
Thank You

Comment: marry, Data passing are controller responsibility. You don't pass one view's value to other. Instead you pass it as query parameter and fetch it in another controller action. And in last line of the action method use the method `renderPartial` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail pass the data to `_form`

Comment: which controller will handle this, one whose view is creating values or whose `_form` will receive values?

Comment: Marry read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/ by the way I can't understand what you are asking. Read definitive guide completely It is easy only.